# Insert multiple "tags" in the database and withdraw them Codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, insert, tags

I looked everywhere but I did not find anything to satisfy my problem, maybe I'll be wrong to look for the way. Using codeigniter, in a page the user sends a post with its relative tags, I wondered how to ensure that in sending the form all the tags were inserted in the database in a separate way, in order to be then taken separately.

I need to create various fields in the database like, tag1, tag2, tag3, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach would be to first create a seperate table for tags.
it can be, id 11 (int), title 100 (varchar), post_id 11 (int)
Then you need to send tags with post submission form.
Insert the post in database and get the inserted record id.
In Controller you need to get the tags from the post array.
Then you need to insert the tags in tags table with posts (primary key i.e. post_id)
You can later get them by post or get directly.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Try these steps**,
Take only one column [varchar(100)] in DataBase->Table to store multiple tags 
I assume your data is in the model via a controller 
At **Insert Time** :
convert your **$_POST data** of Tag (assums in array) in **json with json_encode()** 
At **Update Time** :
Fetch the tags column **convert it json to array** with **json_decode()** then push new tag in it with **array_push()**, keep all tags are unique with the help of **array_unique()** and update it

So, here you dont need to take multiple columns for store multiple tags.